# Android Studio 9 patch file not working but that is not in project

Tags: android, android-studio, nine-patch

I am trying to run android studio latest 2.2 Preview version. On running my project I am getting error[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix this?? The image is not in my project.. probably in some lib I am importing.

Comment: Please find out a 9 patch tutorial

Comment: Even If i can fix the image, how can I change it.. as the file is not in my project. I read on SO that I can rename it from 9.png to .png file but this doesnt help. Where is the file exactly coming from? If I can find that out

Comment: If you can fix the image, then you know where does it come from.

Comment: Unfortunately, you posted your error as a screenshot (too lazy to copy paste?). Therefore I can't show you where the image is. However, its path is indicated in the highlighted line.

Comment: The path is - C:\Users\Nitin\AndroidStudioProjects\Yo\lib\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\

Comment: Then change it there.

Comment: Bro.. I already did.. It is not helping.. that is reason I posted on SO.. Same Error is coming up

Comment: Then you didn't edit the 9 patch correctly. It explicitly tells you what it wants: `a 1px border which has to be transparent`. This would be clear to you, if you were familiar with 9 patches.

Comment: // TODO Keep 2.1.0 for Fix the issue of 9 Patch Images
Used following version in main build.gradle file.
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'